# Storing Facebook User Likes` array in MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook

I have an application which analyzes facebook user likes and shows him/her a video based on that data. Now the question is that I need to store the user like data in MYSQL table. 
the data looks approximately like this

```
array(2) { ["data"]=> array(46) { [0]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> string(21) "Media/news/publishing" ["name"]=> string(20) "Cosmopolitan Armenia" ["id"]=> string(15) "146307748762264" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-03-20T14:40:43+0000" } [1]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> string(17) "Telecommunication" ["name"]=> string(5) "Zangi" ["id"]=> string(15) "386291674718829" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-03-20T11:07:46+0000" } [2]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> string(13) "Musician/band" ["name"]=> string(11) "Ray Charles" ["id"]=> string(12) "430894850091" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-03-16T22:03:46+0000" } [3]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> string(4) "Cars" ["name"]=> string(13) "Mazda Armenia" ["id"]=> string(15) "447042531989769" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-03-16T22:01:46+0000" } [4]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> string(13) "Musician/band" ["name"]=> string(16) "Lockport Artists" ["id"]=> string(15) "615416628475063" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-03-16T21:07:22+0000" }
```

what structure could you recommend for keeping such a data. I could keep in one column as a long text but it will be very unprofessional and the response time will be very high.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your array is called $likes. You could do something like

```
$likes_to_store = json_encode($likes);
```

Then, you'd want to store your `$likes_to_store` in your Database.

Later on, when retrieving the information for use, you would do

```
$likes_to_analyze = json_decode($likes_from_db);
```

This is a clean and easy way to store an array in a database for later use, as the array is serialized into a string, taking up a small amount of space.

Answer (score 1):

My advise, is for you to create a proper table and store each value in a column. Why?
Well values in one column serialized, they're just filling space you can't create proper queries if you want to, in the future you may want to create statistics or use this data to study the behavior of the users or something like that.

So a simple query just to count how many likes of the category "Media/news/publishing" you have, you'll be force to use the like function to find what you need in the serialized data.

And there's nothing more easier that querying your database, retrieve the results as an array and then just serialize with json_encode

Answer (score 0):

The facebook graph replies with JSON.

You can store JSON as a serialized array in MySQL.

However I suggest creating a "Like" class in your application and instantiate and persist "Likes" from the Facebook JSON response.